# Calculate expressions from Run command window

Tags: windows, calculator, run-dialog

Is there a way to quickly get the result of an expression in the Start > Run command input?

For example, if I wanted to get the result of `(5+9)*79` I'd like to be able to press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, enter the expression and get the result.

Are there any lightweight utilities that can do this?

Comment: The Firefox search bar (with Google and search suggestions on) can do that. If you are already in Firefox, you can get to the search bar quickly with Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) has a bundled calcy plugin, which can do what you want.

[image: calcy]

There's also [MathyResurrected](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathyresurected/) plugin for more advanced calculations

[image: MathyResurrected]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do everything from the Run command window, but you could open a Command Prompt (cmd) from there and then execute the `set` command

```
set /a (5+9)*79
```

Just did a search, you could pass everything to cmd and run this from the Run command window

```
cmd /k set /a (5+9)*79
```